# Background doesn't follow? maybe slides behind the divs? not sure how to put it

Tags: html, css, responsive-design

I'm not really sure how to explain the function and therefor I also haven't been able to search the answer (I've tried) but as the titles says, I wanted to try out that effect when it feels like for ex. the header background isn't the one moving when scrolling but the containers that move upwards? A good example is this bootstrap template http://wrapbootstrap.com/preview/WB0915821 
the header and also later on the guy with the glasses, I want to try out that effect with my own website. Could anyone please help me and also tell me wahat you would call that effect/commando?

Comment: Parallax scrolling?

Comment: Thanks Dani I'll look it up =D

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I'm understanding you correctly, you're thinking of parallax scrolling. W3schools has [information](http://www.w3schools.com/howto/howto_css_parallax.asp) on how to implement it. It's mostly just a matter of setting a fixed background element. Here's one of the examples provided by them.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<style>
body, html {
    height: 100%;
}

.parallax {
    /* The image used */
    background-image: url('img_parallax.jpg');

    /* Full height */
    height: 100%;

    /* Create the parallax scrolling effect */
    background-attachment: fixed;
    background-position: center;
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    background-size: cover;
}
</style>
</head>
<body>

<div class="parallax"></div>

<div style="height:1000px;background-color:red;font-size:36px">
Scroll Up and Down this page to see the parallax scrolling effect.
This div is just here to enable scrolling.
Tip: Try to remove the background-attachment property to remove the scrolling effect.
</div>

<div class="parallax"></div>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Wow thank you benjamin, I'm gonna try this out tonight when I get home. Appreciate it very much

Comment: it worked beautifully ! had a little trouble mixing it in my already written code but I got around it. Now one less thing on my to learn list really grateful

Answer (score 1):

try CSS property **[background-attachment:fixed](http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/pr_background-attachment.asp)** on container div.